# How do I "shift" a tcolorbox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I've now tried for about an hour to tikz shift a tcolorbox without any effects. No matter what macros I use, it doesn't seem to work at all. This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a3paper,top=4mm,bottom=4mm,left=4mm,right=4mm]{geometry}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,freelance,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,width=280pt,left=0.5mm,boxrule=0pt,tikz={yshift=0pt,rotate=15,transform shape}]
  \includegraphics[width=270pt]{image1}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,colback=white,width=270pt,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0mm] % halign=center
    \bfseries Blahblah
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,freelance,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,width=280pt,left=0.5mm,boxrule=0pt,tikz={xshift=15cm,rotate=-15,transform shape}]
    \includegraphics[width=270pt]{image2}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,colback=white,width=270pt,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0mm] % halign=center
        \bfseries Blahblah
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if I add `[demo]` to `\usepackage{graphicx}` as I have not got the images, then it runs without error but with several warnings `Overfull \hbox (8.49423pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--25` but you do not say what error or warning you get, not what effect you want to achieve, so it is hard to help

Comment: I want to "freely" move the tcolorbox to where I want it to be. I don't get errors or warnings, it just does nothing.

Comment: What you mean with "freely move"? It appear in text where you put in it. If you like to shift left or right side of text, than this you need to define in tcolorbox.

Comment: what "does nothing"? tcolorbox is positioned like `X` your question is like "how do I shift an `X` ? But the answer depends on where you want to move it to. For example at the moment they are at the start of a justified paragraph so to the left of the page, if you put `\centering` after `\begin{document}` they would be centred, etc.

Comment: Well, the idea is to have the second tcolorbox on the same line as the first but right to it and slightly overlapping.

Answer (score 5):

Put the `tcolorboxe`s inside `node`s and use `\vspace` and `\hspace` to move them.

```
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[a3paper,top=4mm,bottom=4mm,left=4mm,right=4mm]{geometry}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3in}
\mbox{}\hspace{4in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A);
\node[anchor=north west,rotate=15,xshift=3in] (a) at (A) {
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,width=280pt,left=0.5mm,
boxrule=0pt]
  \includegraphics[width=270pt]{example-image-a}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,colback=white,width=270pt,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0mm] % halign=center
    \bfseries Blahblah
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
};
\node[right=of a,xshift=-1.5cm,rotate=-15] (b) {
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,width=280pt,
left=0.5mm,boxrule=0pt]
    \includegraphics[width=270pt]{example-image-b}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,colback=white,width=270pt,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0mm] % halign=center
        \bfseries Blahblah
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Box your `tcolorbox`es and then you can move them at will; I used the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package to vertically align them:

```
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[a3paper,top=4mm,bottom=4mm,left=4mm,right=4mm]{geometry}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newsavebox\myboxa
\newsavebox\myboxb

\begin{lrbox}{\myboxa}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,freelance,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,width=280pt,left=0.5mm,boxrule=0pt,tikz={yshift=0pt,rotate=15,transform shape}]
  \includegraphics[width=270pt]{example-image-a}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,colback=white,width=270pt,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0mm] % halign=center
    \bfseries Blahblah
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{lrbox}
\begin{lrbox}{\myboxb}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,freelance,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,width=280pt,left=0.5mm,boxrule=0pt,tikz={xshift=15cm,rotate=-15,transform shape}]
    \includegraphics[width=270pt]{example-image-b}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,colback=white,width=270pt,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0mm] % halign=center
        \bfseries Blahblah
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{lrbox}

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{valign=c}{\usebox\myboxa}\adjustbox{valign=c}{\hspace*{-40pt}\usebox\myboxb}

\end{document}
```

[image]